The Étale Cohomology from the Variety to its Generic Point
Let $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ and $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $k$, where $k$ contains all $n$-th roots of unity and $\operatorname{char}(k)=p$. Here $p$ and $n$ are coprime. I wonder whether the following map is injective:
$$f: H^{1}_{\text{ét}}(X, \mu_{n})\to H^{1}_{\text{ét}}(K(X), \mu_{n})$$
where $K(X)$ is the function field of $X$, $\mu_{n}$ is the $n$-th cyclic group and the morphism is induced by $\operatorname{Spec}K(X)\to X$.
By applying the $0\to \mu_{n}\to \mathbb{G}_{m}\to \mathbb{G}_{m}\to 0$ to $X$ and $K(X)$, we can get
$0\to \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_{X})^{*}/\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_{X})^{*n}\to  H^{1}_{\text{ét}}(X, \mu_{n})\to \operatorname{Pic}(X)[n]\to 0$ and $H^{1}_{\text{ét}}(K(X),\mu_{n})\cong K(X)^{*}/K(X)^{*n}$.
By snake lemma, $f$ is injective if and only if $\operatorname{Pic}(X)[n]\to K(X)^{*}/K(X)^{*n}/(\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_{X})^{*}/\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_{X})^{*n})$ is injective.
I think the map should be this: Given a $n$-torsion line bundle, we can construct a $n$-th cyclic cover of $X$, it will induce a $n$-th cyclic extension of $K(X)$. So if line bundle map to $1$, it should be trivial line bundle. Thus $f$ should be injective.
Am I correct? It seems this is not a rigorous. Can you give a rigorous proof?
Also, if this is true, it seems this is also true when $X$ is just a locally factorial variety. Am I right?

I asked the question at Math Stack Exchange yesterday. But I did not get an answer. So I ask here again. Hope this is OK.

Since $X$ is regular, it is normal.  Now, for every $\mu_n$-torsor $E\to X$, apply  Zariski’s Main Theorem to extend each rational section to a global section.

Another way to see it: For a $n$-torsion line bundle with divisor $D$, the divisor $nD$ is principal and therefore arises from a rational function $f$. This gives the snake lemma map you write down. If $f$ were the $n$th power of a function $g$ times an invertible global section $h$, then $nD$ is the divisor of $g^n h$ which is the divisor of $g^n$ so $D$ is the divisor of $g$ and hence the original line bundle is trivial. (Normality is exactly what gives us a good theory of divisors.)

Crossposted from MSE.

Let $j : \eta \to X$ denote the inclusion of the generic point into $X$. From the low degree terms of the Leray spectral sequence, we have an exact sequence $$0 \to  H^1(X, j_\ast \mu_n) \to H^1(\eta, \mu_n) $$ and thus it remains to prove that $j_\ast \mu_n = \mu_n$. Let $U \to X$ be an affine etale open. Then since normality is local in the etale topology, $U$ is also normal. In particular, connectedness is equivalent to irreducibility and thus we may assume that $U$ itself is the spectrum of a normal domain $A$ with fraction field $K$.
Let $f\in K$ satisfy $f^n = 1$. Then $f$ is integral over $A$. But $A$ is integrally closed in its field of fractions and hence $f \in A$. This proves that $j_\ast\mu_n = \mu_n$.
